# Analytical solution of a single reservoir system with exponential outflow?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, problem-solving

The reservoir dynamic is the following:

$$
\frac{dS}{dt} = Q_{in} - Q_{out}(t)
$$
with
$$
Q_{out}(t) = k \times S(t)^\alpha
$$

where,

- $S$ is the reservoir storage variable
- $t$ is time
- $Q_{in}$ is the constant inflow
- $Q_{out}(t)$ is the variable outflow
- $k$, $\alpha$ are positive parameters

Is it possible to find an analytical solution for S(t) with given S(t=0) ?
I don't know how to do this anymore without numerical solving.

---

Edit:

Following @(Claude Leibovici)'s answer, analytical solution for $\alpha = 1$ and $\alpha = 2$ with respect to $S(t=0) = S_0$ are:

- $\alpha = 1$

$$
S(t) = \frac{Q_{in}}{k} + \big(S_0 - \frac{Q_{in}}{k}\big) e^{-kt}
$$

- $\alpha = 2$

$$
S(t) = \frac{\sqrt{Q_{in}}}{\sqrt{k}} tanh\big[\sqrt{Q_{in}}\sqrt{k}t+ tanh^{-1} \big(\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{Q_{in}}} S_0 \big)\big)\big]
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that you could get $S(t)$ except if $\alpha=1$ or $\alpha=2$.

However, writing $$\frac{dt}{dS}=\frac{1}{Q_{in}-k S^{\alpha }}\tag 1$$ the solution will be (unfortunately) 
$$t=C+\frac S {Q_{in}} \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{\alpha };\frac{1}{\alpha }+1;\frac{k S^{\alpha   }}{Q_{in}}\right)$$ where appears the hypergeometric function.

I am afraid that you will need numerical integration for the general case.

**Edit**

To show the steps, considering $(1)$, rewrite $$Q_{in}-k S^\alpha=Q_{in}\left(1-\frac k {Q_{in}} S^\alpha\right)$$ Now $$\frac k {Q_{in}} S^\alpha=U^\alpha \implies S=\left(\frac{Q_{in} }k\right)^{\frac 1 \alpha } U\implies dS=\left(\frac{Q_{in} }k\right)^{\frac 1 \alpha } dU$$ which make
$$dt=\frac1{Q_{in} }\left(\frac{Q_{in} }k\right)^{\frac 1 \alpha } \frac{dU}{1-U^\alpha}\implies  \frac{dU}{1-U^\alpha}=Q_{in}\left(\frac{Q_{in} }k\right)^{-\frac {1} \alpha }dt$$ $$\int \frac{dU}{1-U^\alpha}= Q_{in}\left(\frac{Q_{in} }k\right)^{-\frac {1} \alpha }t+C$$ Integrate the lhs to get $U$, go back to $S$ and you are done (for sure, adjust $C$ for the initial condition).

Comment: Thank you for answering. Still, I wonder how could I get the solution for $\alpha$ = 2?

Comment: This is a very simple differential equation. Just separate variables and integrate. The antiderivative is really simple and you know it.

Comment: Simplicity is knowledge dependent, it took me the day but I indeed knew it. The answer is in my edited post. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Delforge. I totally agree with *simplicity is knowledge dependent* but this is what you are acquiring in your studies. Now about *it took me the day* : I supposed that you tried to go too fast; You can make the problem much nicer using small intermediate steps. I add them in an edit in my answer. In any manner, **I** thank you for having done the work and I upvoted your post. Cheers.